# IS there a concise way to specify all verbs when defining a module mapping in iis

Tags: windows, iis

I'm trying to wrap my head around setting up a module mapping for IIS in a script. I've got the command

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:handlers /+"[path='*.cgi',modules='CgiModule',name='vscgi',verb='get,head,post']"
```

which does pretty much everything I need, however, instead of explicitly accepting three verbs, I would rather just accept all verbs (like the system does by default when defining a module mapping via the UI). Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes there is!

Specify the verb attribute value as `'*'`, just like in the [sample code provided on IIS.NET](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/handlers/add):

```
appcmd set config /section:handlers /+"[path='*.cgi',modules='CgiModule',name='vscgi',verb='*']"
```

Comment: Thank you! I had been looking at the tutorials on technet and that wasn't specified. I'll mark this as correct when the time limit expires.

Comment: Granted, the TechNet articles on the subject are a bit lacking, but on the other hand, IIS.NET *is* the offical IIS product site and the [Configuration Reference there](http://www.iis.net/configreference) is authoritive and *very* thorough. Worth bookmarking